# Importing a Python Module inside Custom Django Templatetags

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-import

I'm using `virtualenv` with my Python Django installation.

Here is my **directory structure**:

```
project/
    dev_environ/
        lib/
            python2.6/
                site-packages/
                    ...
                    django/
                    titlecase/   # <-- The titlecase module
                    PIL/
                    ...
        bin/
            ...
            python  # <-- Python
            ...
        include/

    django_project/
        localsite/
            templatetags/
                __init__.py
                smarttitle.py    # <-- My templatetag module
        foo_app/
        bar_app/
        settings.py
        manage.py
```

If I start my Django shell and attempt to import `titlecase` everything is fine, because `titlecase` is in the `sys.path` at `dev_environ/lib/python2.6/site-packages/titlecase`.

```
$:django_project cwilcox$ ../dev_environ/bin/python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import titlecase  # <-- No Import Error!
>>>
```

I can even do an `import titlecase` inside my `settings.py` file without error.

However when I try to `import titlecase` in my templatetag library `smarttitle.py` I get an `ImportError`.

**smarttitle.py** is as follows.

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
register = template.Library()
from titlecase import titlecase as _to_titlecase

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def smarttitle(value):
    return _to_titlecase(value)
smarttitle.is_safe = True
```

Not only that but I can even `import titlecase` inside the view that renders the template that tries to `{% load smarttitle %}` and there's no error.

My Django dev server is started with...

```
../dev_environ/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

*In Summary:*

I can import the `titlecase` module *anywhere* except inside this templatetag library, where it throws an `ImportError`! What gives?! Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: I tried first running `source dev_environ/bin/activate` to switch my shell env to my virtualenv, but that didn't help--I'm still getting the ImportError inside my templatetag module. I was already calling the proper python binary manually.

Comment: Might be a daft question, but you are doing 'source dev_environ/bin/activate' or similar?

Comment: I don't know what `source dev_environ/bin/activate` is. Sounds like I'm missing something important. I figured all I'd have to do when I installed something was `dev_environ/bin/pip install <module>`.

Comment: Running 'source <virtualenv dir>/bin/activate' changes your $PATH to point to the virtualenv directory - instead of the global python install on your computer. In terminal, try running 'source dev_environ/bin/activate' followed by 'python manage.py runserver' - it should all work properly?

Comment: @user608 OK I looked up what `bin/activate` does. It looks like that just modifies your shell, I was already calling the proper bin/python directly so I don't think thats the issue (I will edit to make that more clear).

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you need to activate your virtualenv by doing `source bin/activate` (or just `. bin/activate`) before running the devserver, even if you are already accessing the right Python executable.

Comment: As I said in my recent edit at the bottom there, even when I switch to the dev environment using `source bin/activate` there is no change. I still do NOT get errors when I import from within the Django `manage.py shell` and I still DO get errors when I import from within templatetags inside the development server started with `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: If it isn't an issue with your $PATH - then it may be to do with how titlecase is being installed. I have a similar issue with PIL - 'easy_install PIL' installs it, but badly (though if I remember correctly, still importable in the shell) - 'pip install PIL' works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is too old, but I get a similar problem today.

The problem seems to be **using the same name for the app and the module**, so when it tries to import it could fail looking for the desired module or function in the wrong place.

I recommend you to give **different names** to the django app or module.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a fix, but just to establish that we are looking at the same problem/bug:

If you change the import in `smarttitle.py` to

```
from YOURPROJECT.titlecase import titlecase as _to_titlecase
```

it will work with 'runserver' but it will fail on production (in my case uwsgi/nginx)